# looking for object with certain local variable in an array list

Tags: java, loops

I have an array list "comps" of an object components each component has a specific ID.
I want to search the array for a components with a certain ID use it in a method flip.

```
for(int i=0; i<comps.size(); i++){
                    if(a==comps[i].sourceID){
                        comps[i].flip();
                    }
                }
```

I did this but it is not working as I expect it to do. I get an error saying "Array required, but ArrayList found"

Comment: what datatype is your sourceID?

Comment: Is the ID an `int` or `String`? If it is `String`, use `equals`, not `==`. About your error: Use `comps.get(i)`.

Comment: source ID is integer

Comment: If comps is the arraylist, you can turn it to array with comps.toArray(); method, it will not turn comps into one, but will return it, so you might need an another variable to hold it.

Answer (score 3):

You are using ArrayList which means that you can't use brackets for indexing, what you should do is:

```
for(int i=0; i<comps.size(); i++){
    if(a==comps.get(i).sourceID){
         comps.get(i).flip();
    }
}
```

Also I suggest you to look into streams, which makes it easier

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access array member by []. you should try comps.get(i)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A list does not have indexing like Arrays, use comps.get(i) for lists. For more options write down comps. and look what the IDE suggests you. There are neat things a list can do.
Should look something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<comps.size(); i++) {
if( a==comps.get(i).sourceID ) {
     comps.get(i).flip(); }
}
```